# Making a screensaver

Tags: xml, windows, directx, screensaver

No, I'm not talking about making a slideshow of pictures.  How can I make the actual file that windows (at least windows 7) uses for screensavers?

It is a .scr format, and when I opened it in Notepad, I got a bunch of symbols, with a few words scattered throughout, but that was expected.  It looks like it was made with directx, xml, and even assembly (for the shaders) based on the recognizable code there.

I just went on to a site-hosting place and made this:

[Link to ribbons.scr code](http://stackoverflowquestion.webs.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is an example of how making a screensaver.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686421(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what that link does.  It seems to be grabbing some rss file from the os.  I'm looking for a screensaver, and I don't think that is one.

Comment: Whoops, my bad.  I just looked right over the part with the answer, or at least what I think is the answer.  Is it really as easy as just adding 5 lines of code to the project file, and everything works right?  As a followup, how can I add it into the Windows directory for screensavers?  Right-click->Install?

Comment: AFAIK in Windows7, yes, you have to right-click->install.